# CE transistor curves

Tags: transistors, common-emitter

I've created the following simulation on LTSpice and I'm running a DC sweep for V1, I1: .dc V1 0 5 5m I1 0 100u 10u.

After the simulation is finished, I get those two graphs for \$ V_c=f(V_b)\$ and \$I_c=f(I_{b})\$.

[image]

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwEPv6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can someone help me understand what I am seeing in those graphs? I was expecting that the voltage on the collector would start at the max value \$V_1\$ as the transistor is in saturation mode and then it would drop to \$ \approx 0V\$ as the transistor is getting into the cutoff region. I am not seeing that here and I'm confused about what equations describe that problem. How can I calculate the voltage and current gain using those graphs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Vc=V1, it's not a dependent variable. You probably want to plot Ic=f(Vc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you'd like, but try the following schematic:

[image]

When you run it, click carefully on the collector of \$Q_1\$ so that you get the current displayed:

[image]

It's as easy as that to get a nice display that also includes the Early Effect. You can replace the BJT model, as desired, of course.

---

The only difficulty I see in your first panel is the green curve at the left. To fix that, start your current at something OTHER than 0, like I did. The rest of the curves on that first panel just show the \$V_{BE}\$ values. Which don't look unreasonable (not knowing the BJT model you are using.)

Here's mine (after adjusting to your \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ limits):

[image]

This makes ***complete*** sense. (Perhaps it would make a lot more sense to *you* if you were to have swapped the X and Y axis parameters. I'd recommend trying that and see if the insight dawns, immediately.)

Each curve is based upon first setting a current into the base. So, in my example, this would be \$I_B=10\:\mu\textrm{A}\$. Then it sweeps \$V_{CE}\$ from \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ in millivolt steps. That's what was requested in my case. So each curve is developed in that fashion. The X axis is \$V_{BE}\$ and the Y axis is \$V_{CE}\$.

When \$V_{CE}\$ is very tiny, it's obvious that the transistor is also very saturated. (If you were to zoom up into the first few millivolts for \$V_{CE}\$ you might even see cases where the collector current is *less* than the base current!) The value of \$V_{BE}\$ will remain fairly flat (especially on a linear scale -- try setting your Y axis to logarithmic!) for quite a while at \$I_B=10\:\mu\textrm{A}\$, because a saturated BJT doesn't move much in \$V_{CE}\$ until you reach the point where it leaves saturation and the \$\beta\$ starts to kick in. Then \$V_{CE}\$ can move. Same with each successive curve. It's really no mystery at all. You just need to wrap your mind around the idea. And I don't know how to create that break-through for you. You just need to work. It cannot be handed to you on a platter without me writing MANY PARAGRAPHS.

The second panel you provide is also quite normal. The \$\beta\$ is about 190 or so for your device. Don't you see why it works out that way??? (Take the value of the base current for a given line, multiply it by 190, and that should give you the approximate height you see.) Here's mine:

[image]

Comment: I am getting this curve. I can't explain the form of the other two curves though.

Comment: @Bill I added a note.

Comment: So, I calculate the β value for each line and not for all of them using the formula β=ΔIc/ΔIb, got it. Can you explain why the graph Vce versus Vbe is acceptable? I don't seem to understand why.

Comment: @Bill I gave it a shot. You just need to work this through your mind. I can't hand this to you on a platter. It's very easy for me to see. You just need to wrestle this down. Be aware of saturation vs active modes, is the best I can quickly do to help you. Other than that, I'd have to write many paragraphs. And my fingers are tired.

Comment: good lord, thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Bill I hope it helped and would be glad to hear if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I1: .dc V1 0 5 5m I1 0 100u 10u.

When Vc=V1 0 5
- V1 sweeps 0 up to 5V there is 0 current and Vbe=0 . The beginning of the sweep with Ib=0 shows the leakage voltage to the base with the current source being infinite impedance.
- the next sweeps with 10u+ show the Rbe (Rpi) initial slope with increasing Vbe then output sweep pulls to 5V since you have no series load limiting R.

Problem;  When you sweep a voltage controlled current sink into an ideal sweeping voltage source, the output impedance is zero of V1. For linear operating range, choose Rc = Vmax/Imax

### Solution:

add a suitable series Rc to V1.  Then plot Ic vs Ib , Vce vs Ic and then Vbe vs Ic all with a fixed series load R.

From the last curve you will have a slope indicating Rce internal resistance during saturation ( Vce<2V) or at *de facto* spec Vce(sat) at Ic/Ib=10